# Div Centralizada

Tags: css

Esta minha div não fica no meio da tela,  esta errado o estilo CSS ?

```
<div style="position:absolute;margin:auto;">
    <img src="assets/img/PHP.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Tente usar 
<center><div>
    <img src="assets/img/PHP.png"/>
</div></center>

Comment: Tente dar um tamanho a div (width) e colocar margin 0 auto.

Comment: Assim
    <center><div> <img src="assets/img/PHP.png"/> </div></center>

Comment: Certo,  porem preciso que ela fique acima do meu rodapé ,  e longe de botton 50px

Comment: No meio na vertical, na horizontal, ou as duas coisas?

Comment: por isso preciso de position:absolute   e botton:50px

Comment: Para a imagem ficar centralizada na tela horizontalmente e acima da parte inferior 50px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.div{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: black;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
   <img src="test.jpg">
</div>
```

Segue um exemplo..

Depois de ler os comentarios a cima, segue a edição

```css
.div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    
  </div>
```

Exemplo atualizado

```css
.div{
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -50px;
      bottom: 30px;
      z-index: 99999999
    }
    
footer{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background: black;
      margin-top: 200px;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <img src="https://forum.imasters.com.br/uploads/monthly_2017_02/mascote.png">
</div>

<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Para a imagem ficar centralizada na tela horizontalmente e acima na parte inferior 50px   ?

Comment: Assim ela esta ficando acima  
teria que ser 50px da parte debaixo da tela

Comment: @PauloMaia Não entendi, você quer, centralizar a imagem e deixa-la na parte inferior com 50px de distancia do bottom?

Comment: @PauloMaia voce consegue colocar uma imagem de exemplo, para ficar mais facil o entendimento?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo,   a imagem precisa ficar na parte inferior da minha pagina ( em modo flutuante ) para ficar acima do meu rodapé existente e 50px descolada da parte inferior

Comment: Veja exemplo do mascote do imaster Forum veja esse link e va até o final da pagina  https://forum.imasters.com.br/

Comment: Rafael, coloca `bottom: 50px;` e pronto, não?

Comment: Assim ? <div style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -50px; bottom: 50px;"> <img src="assets/img/PHP.png"/> </div>

Comment: @PauloMaia sim, mas melhor usar uma classe do que tudo assim no style...

Comment: @PauloMaia Atualizei o codigo

Comment: POREM AO ROLAR A PAGINA A IMAGEM VAI JUNTO QUANDO DEVERIA FICAR L NO RODAPÉ

Comment: e não esta centralizada  usei a class div  como orientou

Comment: Ainda não funcionou

Comment: @PauloMaia como assim nao funcionou? qual o problema atual?

Comment: ao carregar a pagina a imagem aparece não centralizada porem uns 30% da esquerda e ela deveria aparecer lá no rodapé somente quando eu rolar até meu rodapé é que vou ver ela centralizada em cima do meu rodapé.

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer ficar no rodapé e centralizada

Comment: @PauloMaia vou montar outro exemplo

Comment: OK Pois aqui fazendo alterações no css ainda não consegui

Comment: @Rafael Augusto  ,  algum exito ?